# Mitchell FPL 3.6.2 (Show that equation does not hold in initial algebra)

Tags: semantics, operational-semantics

Mitchell specifies a set data type: ie, an algebraic specification for set. He then asks to prove that the equation

*union s s' = union s' s [s, s': set]*

does not hold in the initial algebra. He suggests that we use the following result: two terms are provably equal iff they reduce to a common term. Here are the relevant reduction steps:

*union empty s -> s*

*union (insert y s) s' -> insert y (union s s')*

attempt: we can destruct on s, s' ( a previous result shows that all sets are constructed from the empty set and the insert constructor, which takes a nat and adds it to a set to produce a new set). In the case that both s, s' are nonempty, we apply the relevant reduction steps  and obtain

*insert y (union P s')* from the LHS

*insert x (union Q s)* from the RHS

Further, Mitchell also proves that all sets (according to his specification) are finite. So after a finite number of times this process terminates for both LHS and RHS. Then, we see that the resulting terms are both in normal form, but not syntactically identifical, hence by hypothesis, not provably equal from the specification.

Qa: for destructing, I have not treated the cases where s, s' are both empty, in which case, they reach a common term. It seems intuitive that they must reach a common term in all four cases in order for me to say that LHS, RHS both reduce to a common term but this is not what the theorem says, which perhaps suggests that I shouldn't have destructed? But I don't see any other way to go about this.

Qb: supposing this works, we have shown that the specification does not prove the given equation. Mitchell does say that initial algebras satisfy the least number of possible equations (they are somewhat like free groups). He also says intial algebra satisfies M= N iff every ground instance of M=N is provable from the specification, where a ground instance is just a substition of all variables in the term to a closed/variable free term. Perhaps I can just stubstitue x with say "3" and y with "4" and then conclude? Or how would I go about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all you need to show is that `union a b = union b a` is not provable, where `a` and `b` are variables, it suffices to find one particular instance where the equation does not hold, so how about:

```
union (insert 42 empty) (insert 13 empty) = union (insert 13 empty) (insert 42 empty)
```

The left-hand side rewrites to `insert 42 (insert 13 empty)` and the right-hand side to `insert 13 (insert 42 empty)`. These are reduced and not equal so we are done.